# Asp.net C# Capture Output to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

I'm writing because I'm stuck on a problem, I have code that currently writes the output of an aspx page to a word document.  This code works perfectly fine.  However I need to actually save that file to the server.  Here is the code that is working:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=IR-" + lblReportNumber.Text + ".doc");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(this.Page.ToString());
```

Here is what I have tried to do to get the desired results

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), "IR-" + lblReportNumber.Text + ".doc");
string page = this.Page.ToString();
```

The problem is, the *.doc* file that's written to the server only contains the page name for text and not the full contexts of the html.

So if I open the word document from my second set of code all I see is "clientpage.aspx"  however the first block of code opens the fully formatted word doc.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your first code doesn't actually do anything. It only works because ASP.Net is writing the rest of the page to the response anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You need to actually write to the file using `StreamWriter`

like

> ```
>     using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("filename")
>     {
>            file.WriteLine()
>     }
> ```

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is something new to me, so I'm not really clear how to implement it.  How do I pass the entire page to the streamwriter?